# Missing user principals when using EarlyExecutionFilter from Magnolia

Tags: forwarding, magnolia

I have some problems with the EarlyExectionFilter from magnolia. When forwarding to the webpage which was given back from my executeEarly() method, the system can't forward to the given path since the user principals are not set to the subject. When i send a redirect, the Filter works fine. After two days of debugging I couldn't find the error, any ideas how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Look in your filter chain. My guess would be that you have EarlyExecutionFilter before SecurityFilter so it is executed before authentication is done. It works with the redirect because filter chain is executed again after the redirect thus on second pass user is already authenticated and EEF will see it.

If this is indeed the case, solution is then to move EE filter after SecurityFilter.

HTH,
Jan